# Is react-native-video supports HLS video format in android?

Tags: react-native, m3u8, react-native-video

Is react-native-video supports Hls video in android ?
or what to do for playing hls video from aws s3 bucket using react-native-video?please help i am new to react-native

Answer (score 0):

You can check this package for React Native;
[React Native VLC Media Player](https://github.com/razorRun/react-native-vlc-media-player)

"Support for network streams, RTSP, RTP, RTMP, HLS, MMS"

And all other formats. You can check and look into it if it fits for you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).